# How to retrieve data corresponding to a particular UITableViewCell from core data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm doing a project in swift 3.0 and I have two UIViewControllers and one of them has three text fields. In that UIViewController once the data is entered in the textfields and when the save button is pressed the data will be saved to core data. In my core data module, the name of my entity is "Task" and it has got four attributes namely: amount, age, name and  isImportant(all are strings except the last one). The code is shown below

```
import UIKit


class AddTaskViewController: UIViewController {

    var isRowTapped :Bool?

    @IBOutlet weak var textFiels: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var isImp: UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

    @IBAction func buttonTabbed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let context =  (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        let task = Task(context: context)
        task.name = textFiels.text
        task.age = firstTextField.text
        task.amount = secondTextField.text
        task.isImportant = isImp.isOn
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

        print("Data saved successfully")

        navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)

    }



}
```

Even though three values will be saved to core data, only the attribute called "name" will be taken out from core data and will be printed on cells in the second view controller where i have my table view (it is more like an identity name). What I want to know is since I'm entering three values initially to core data in the initial view controller, once a particular row is selected in the second view controller how do I get all the three values to correspond to that name attribute and re-assign them to my text fields in the initial view controller so that I could edit them and save again. The code of my second view controller is as below (tableviewViewController).

```
import UIKit

class DispalyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    var tasks : [Task] = []
    var isRowSelected :Bool = false
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        loadData()
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func loadData(){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        do {
            tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())
            print("fetch sucess")
        }catch{
            print("fetch failed")
        }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("count is : \(tasks.count)")
        return tasks.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell ()
        print("table view loaded")
        let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
        if task.isImportant{
            cell.textLabel?.text = " \(task.name!)"
        }else{
            cell.textLabel?.text = task.name
        }
        return cell


     }


     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowNxtVC", sender: nil)
        //isRowSelected = true
     }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let selectedRow = segue.destination as! AddTaskViewController
       //selectedRow.isRowTapped = isRowSelected

    }

//For swipe access allow

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let task = tasks [indexPath.row]
            context.delete(task)
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
        do {
            tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())
        }catch{
            print("fetchinh failed")
        }


    }
    tableview.reloadData()
  }

}
```

Comment: You are only fetching the name field form the core data with "task.name". try to fetch other like wise. task.amount, etc. Is that what you mean to ask?

Comment: No sir... Lets say that one entry has three values (they will be entered in three disticnt text fields) and im fetching only one value as i need to populated it in my table view. But once a particular row is selected i need to fetch the rest also which correspond to that entry. 

eg :-  the three text fields are to enter the name, age ,and pay (once all three entered this will be taken as one entry) 

Then in my table view controller i'llm be taking the attribute called "name" from the entity called "Task"  and assign all the names to an array (as in the code) and populate them on cells.

Comment: Ok, You can fetch by setting extra query during fetching the core data for next vc on click of table row. But I would suggest do in this way, take a model object class and configure your model object to hold all the value of core data (i.e 4 values in your case). Then as you are saying you are able to fetch the data from core data and add the name only in the array, So in spite of storing only name in the array, store all the data in model object and store the model object in array. To be continued ...

Comment: Then in cellForRowAtIndex fetch the model object from the array and then by dot operator show the name value. And on click of table cell pass the model object to next vc, as the model object has all value, you can easily get. Do you understand ?

Comment: Oh yes, Task is the object i guess, so from tasks you will get other values using dot operator. Check and let me know if you find it

Comment: Sir I'm very new to swift, would you be kind enough to tell me how can i create this model class and fetch data from it. Plus how can i save data to this model class

Comment: I can check and change it there if you can send your project. It would be a waste of time to create a demo for you.

Comment: ok pass me your email

Comment: Put in dropbox and share the link here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rjhr5o2vun7dxxs/AADUTzkbumi1AuDmMWBCKWz8a?dl=0

Comment: Your code was showing error, may be i was running in swift 2. So i have demonstrated how to use core data here : https://github.com/janmenjayarout/Swift_Coredata_Sample. Let me kn ow if it helps you.

Comment: yes as sir this is written in swift 3.0 thats why

Comment: Ok that is fine, from the demonstration you can get to know how it works and then you can convert it to swift 3, I hope that is not hard to do.